# Bot Framework: Handle incorrect user inputs

Tags: node.js, botframework

I've built a bot that asks user to upload an attachment. But I also want to give the ability to the user to just type any text instead of uploading an attachment, but whenever I do that it says

> I didn't receive a file. Please try again.

In the command line, I can see it says `no intent handler found for null`. How do I handle these nulls/incorrect inputs?

Sample code:

```
intents.matchesAny([/lost and found/i], [
    function (session) {
        builder.Prompts.attachment(session,"Please upload a picture of the item.");  
     },

    function (session) {
        session.endConversation('Thank you');
    }
]);
```

Comment: Hi @Arish, any update now? Looking forward for your news.

Answer (score 1):

Per your issue message, `no intent handler found for null`, which seems that you are using `builder.IntentDialog`, and the issue means that your bot didn't match any intents provided in your bot.

Also I notice that your are using `intents.matchesAny`, according to the comment:

> `Invokes a handler when any of the given intents are detected in the users utterance.` So I think you forget to set such intent `lost and found` in your LUIS server.

If you want to trigger any miss catched user utterance, you can try to use:

```
intents.onDefault([
    function (session) {
        builder.Prompts.attachment(session,"Please upload a picture of the item.");  
     },

    function (session) {
        session.endConversation('Thank you');
    }
]);
```